# Pass instance of model in method parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a common class for models, where I am passing the model instance to my separate parameter

```
class Custom
{

    private $model;

    public function getAll()
    {

        return $this->model->get();
    }

    public function  setModel(Model $model)
    {

        $this->model=$model;

    }
}
```

and my controller I have

```
$customModel=new Custom();
$customModel->setModel(Branch::class);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($customModel->getAll());
```

and also I tried

```
$response=$this->customDatatable->setModel(Branch::class)->getAll();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response->toArray());
```

but I got the following Error

> Argument 1 passed to App\Helpers\Custom::setModel() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given, called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Branch::class` is a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) that returns the class name as a string, as the error message suggests. Perhaps you're looking to pass `new Branch` instead.

Comment: @miken.Thanks is there any way i can improve other than passing instance

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.